# Ruby on Rails: setting future "publishing" dates for blog postings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to set blog postings to publish at certain dates in the future. I have in my Posting model:

```
 named_scope :published, :conditions => ["publish_at <= ?", Time.now]
```

I'm using this in my controller to call the published postings:

```
  @postings = Posting.published
```

The development server works fine, but I believe the production server needs me to refresh the cache (using "pkill -9 dispatch.fcgi") or I won't see the new postings when it's supposed to publish.

Is there any way to set future times for the postings' publishing dates correctly on the production server? Do I have to refresh the cache every time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct, because the named scope is evaluated when the class loads.

You should re-write it to be dynamic or (maybe better) use the database's now() function.

Either of these should work:

```
named_scope :published, lambda { {:conditions => ["publish_at <= ?", Time.now]} }
```

Note how this uses a lambda to always return the current time in the conditions hash.

```
named_scope :published, :conditions => "publish_at <= now()"
```

This is database dependent (the above should work for MySQL) but probably a tiny bit faster.

Comment: Interesting. Doesn't seem to be described that way here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NamedScope/ClassMethods.html

Comment: No problem. I ran into a very similar issue a few months ago so I'd already been through it.

Comment: I just tried this, and I needed:

named_scope :published, lambda { { :conditions => ["publish_at <= ?", Time.now] } }

2 sets of brackets. Seems to work for me ....

Comment: Oops, you're right, I've run into that problem before. I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if you have any of the following statements in your production environment:

```
 ActionController::Base.cache_store = :memory_store
```

OR

```
 ActionController::Base.cache_store = :file_store, "/path/to/cache/directory"
```

OR

```
 ActionController::Base.cache_store = :mem_cache_store
```

OR any other setting for `ActionController::Base.cache_store`

Comment: Hi Ron. I don't have any of those. I only these:

config.cache_classes = true
config.action_controller.consider_all_requests_local = false
config.action_controller.perform_caching             = true

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure why you're seeing this effect.

Comment: It seems like it doesn't publish instantly (I did see a post whose publishing date was a few hours prior publish okay). I'm thinking that maybe it just takes a few hours or so before Rails resets or something.

Comment: My first thought was that it was taking a while to refresh SQL cache, but those are supposed to be expunged at the end of each request. Are you sure you don't have any caching set up? No memcached or similar?

Comment: By "taking a while" I mean "until the process died" since you mentioned that killing the process was effective.

Comment: I don't believe I have any cache set up (just those 3 lines above). It's probably my code though so I'll try to pinpoint the issue somehow. Thanks a bunch for the great help Ron.